# Problems connecting to MySQL db in EC2 instance (iOS/AFNetworking)

Tags: mysql, ios, apache, afnetworking

I'm having such a frustrating time figuring this out. I'm making a login/registration function for an iOS app that's working fine on my local server. I want to import it to an actual server but I have been having very little success. I included sample code at the end of this for reference.

I set up an EC2 instance and made sure to open port 3306 in the security group ([seen here](http://ec2-54-215-166-236.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com/sg.png)). The problem I'm having is when I try to make the initial connection to the instance via the app. When I connect to `http://54.215.166.236` in API.m (my instance's elastic IP) I do not get a successful connection. By that I mean, the failure block on this method gets called:

`[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:  failure: ];`

However, the php files do get run before the success/failure determination and this is what I see in the apache error logs:

> mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1130): Host '54.215.166.236' is not allowed
>   to connect to this MySQL server in /var/www/html/php/lib.php on line 6

And that's when I'm accessing the MySQL db via:

```
$link = mysqli_connect("54.215.166.236","user","password");
mysqli_select_db($link, "db");
```

But when I change the address to include the 3306 port I get...

```
$link = mysqli_connect("54.215.166.236:3306","user","password");
mysqli_select_db($link, "db");
```

> mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2005): Unknown MySQL server host
>   '54.215.166.236:3306' (0) in /var/www/html/php/lib.php on line 6

Again, this is all when I try to make the initial instance connection with the address `http://54.215.166.236`. Therefore, this tells me that I'm successfully connecting to the EC2 instance, but I'm not connecting to the MySQL database which is why I get sent to the `failure:` block

When I go back and change that initial connection address in API.m to `http://54.215.166.236:3306`, the connection proceeds to the `setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:` block, however I get no log output from apache, php, or mysql and no entries in the server database. It's as if the php files aren't being executed. In fact, this is probably exactly what's happening, because when I try and go to run php files like `http://54.215.166.236:3306/index.php`, my browser attempts to download the php file, rather than executing it. This is why I'm so confused. If there's no attempt at even logging into the MySQL database (because no log output and no successful input of data in the db), why does adding 3306 port on initial connection give me a "successful" connection?

I'm at such a loss here. I've been stuck on this issue for days. I could really use some help here. I'll include some sample code that illustrates my problem:

---

```
//Test.m
@implementation

[API sharedInstance]

@end
```

.

```
//API.h
typedef void (^JSONResponseBlock)(NSDictionary* json);

@interface API : AFHTTPClient
...
@end


//API.m
#define kAPIHost @"http://54.215.166.236:3306"
#define kAPIPath @"php/"

@implementation API

@synthesize user;

+ (API *) sharedInstance
{
    static API *sharedInstance = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t oncePredicate;
    dispatch_once(&oncePredicate, ^{
        sharedInstance = [[self alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:kAPIHost]];
    });

    //Just making some test parameters to store in the db
    NSMutableDictionary *params =[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                  @"register", @"command",
                                  @"name", @"username",
                                  @"pass", @"password",
                                  nil];

    [sharedInstance commandWithParams:params
                         onCompletion:^(NSDictionary *json) 
                         {                            
                            NSLog(@"Error: %@", [json objectForKey:@"error"]);                                    
                         }];

    return sharedInstance;
}

- (void) commandWithParams: (NSMutableDictionary *) params
              onCompletion: (JSONResponseBlock)completionBlock
{
    NSMutableURLRequest *apiRequest =
    [self multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST"
                                    path:kAPIPath
                              parameters:params
               constructingBodyWithBlock: ^(id <AFMultipartFormData>formData) {
               }];

    AFJSONRequestOperation* operation = [[AFJSONRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest: apiRequest];
    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) 
    {
        //success!
        completionBlock(responseObject);
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        //failure :(
        completionBlock([NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[error localizedDescription] forKey:@"error"]);
    }];

    [operation start];
}


    //intialize the API class with the destination host name

- (API *) init
{
    //call super init
    self = [super init];

    if (self != nil) {
        //initialize the object
        user = nil;

        [self registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFJSONRequestOperation class]];

        // Accept HTTP Header
        [self setDefaultHeader:@"Accept" value:@"application/json"];
    }

    return self;
}

@end
```

I'm not going to include all the PHP, but just the relevant part:

```
$link = mysqli_connect("54.215.166.236:3306","user","password");
mysqli_select_db($link, "db");
```

Comment: You're going to drive yourself crazy trying to get your client working before your server works.  Make sure you know the exact request your server is expecting.  Download Rest Client (http://bit.ly/MuID5O) or something similar and get your apache config working first.  You probably need to add php to your conf or htaccess file, but I'm not an apache expert.  Then, when your php/sql is working, connect with AFNetworking.  On a side note, you don't need a multi-part form request to just post some parameters.

Comment: @AaronBrager Thanks for the comment Aaron. Could you elaborate a little more on this. Why would my instance properly handle php without a port, but then when I add :3306, the php files are mishandled and not executed, but downloaded? I can't seem to find a way around this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working. Turns out I was sending off the port parameter incorrectly with the [mysqli_connect() function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php) which clearly shows the port being the fifth parameter. The initial connection in iOS to the EC2 instance should also NOT contain the port in the address. These are the settings I used that worked:

```
#define kAPIHost @"http://54.215.166.236"

$link = mysqli_connect("54.215.166.236","user","password", "db", "3306");
```